# how make control validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `Checkdate`. I want to connect this function to a save button when the user addss an event.

If the date exists, the save button shouldn't work:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    //Validation/

    if ($('#txtSubject').val().trim() == "") {
        alert('Subject required');
        return;
    }
    if ($('#txtStart').val().trim() == "") {
        alert('Start date required');
        return;
    }
    if ($('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') == false && $('#txtEnd').val().trim() == "") {
        alert('End date required');
        return;
    }
    else {
        var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
        var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
        if (startDate > endDate) {
            alert('Invalid end date');
            return;
        }
    }

    SaveEvent(data);
    // call function for submit data to the server
})
```

This is my function:

```
$('#btnSave').click (function () {
    var StartDate = $('#txtStart').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Checkdate",
        data: '{StartDate: "' + StartDate + '" }', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var message = $("#message");
            if (response) {
                //Email available.
                message.css("color", "green");
                message.html(" date is not exist ");
            }
            else {
                //Email not available.
                message.css("color", "red");
                message.html("date existe ");
            }
        }
    });
});

function ClearMessage() {
    $("#message").html("");
}
```

I hope you look at this image to understand me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzaeD.jpg)

Comment: What is not working? Can you show the code in `/Home/Checkdate`?

Comment: it work but when i click in button save the events added i want when the date is exist the button save must not work

Comment: `Checkdate` needs to return a response, preferably in JSON format. Your function that receives the response should `JSON.parse()` it and determine what to do based on the response.